# MYSQL -what is the best practice for checking if multiple phone numbers exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

my table contains 5 milion enteries of phone numbers. suppose i need to check if a specific phone numbers exist in that table - i got an input of 1 milion numbers, and need to check what numbers exist in my table - the result has to be under 20 seconds - what is the query for this ?

Comment: Careful! If you haven't read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Telephone Numbers](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md), please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create one new table for 1 million of phone numbers.

- tableA: 5 million of phone numbers
- tableB: 1 million of phone numbers

2. Create index for tableA's phone numbers field and tableB's field
3. Execute the below SQL script

```sql
select 
  tableA.phoneNumber, 
  .... 
from 
  tableA 
where EXISTS(select * from tableB where tableA.phoneNumber=tableB.phoneNumber)
```

According to your request, please use the below sql script.

*I strongly discourage this because it does not use the index of numbersFromRequest.*

```sql
SELECT number
FROM 
    (SELECT '0546313243' number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '0527844910' number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '0542307563' number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '0587918462' number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '0545496228' number ) AS numbersFromRequest
WHERE NOT exists 
    (SELECT 1 from PhoneNumber
    where PhoneNumber.number = numbersFromRequest.number)
```

Also, I create some data for your testing. [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f1c014e21faf018076b15a3a6a2b21ad)

Like this as below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE numbersFromRequest
  (number varchar(20), INDEX USING BTREE (number))
  ENGINE = MEMORY;

INSERT INTO numbersFromRequest(number)
SELECT '0546313243' number
UNION ALL
SELECT '0527844910' number
UNION ALL
SELECT '0542307563' number
UNION ALL
SELECT '0587918462' number
UNION ALL
SELECT '0545496228' number
```

And then you can use temp table.

Comment: thanks, the thing is that instead of tableA - i get the phones as an input (from a request), and i form it together in a query with UNION ALL  and serach forn them in tableB- and the query is to big - 
my query is - 
select number from 
(
select 0546313243 number union all 
select 0527844910 number union all 
select 0542307563 number union all 
select 0587918462 number union all 
select 0545496228 number 
) as numbersFromRequest where number NOT IN (select PhoneNumber from tableB) - is there a way to optimize it ?

Comment: thanks - that exactly what im doing, but im getting a timeout from the DB when im sending a large amount of numbers - say 1 milion numbers

Comment: So I asked you to create a new table to store 1 million numbers.

Comment: so creating a tamprory table and inserting 2 milion entries and comparing will take less time?

Comment: Temporary table can help you. numbersFromRequest is a key point. Don't forget to create one index on numbersFromRequest for number. On your table contains 5 million enterprise of phone numbers, you also need to add one index in number field.

Comment: can you explain more please? i dont see how creating new table and inserting 2 milion entries, and then finding the not existed numbers  in tableB will not end up in tomeout